# Java: проверить валидность пути к файлу

Tags: java

Дано: на вход метода приходит файл и путь, куда этот файл локально сохранить. Путь вида `/opt/docstorage/foo/bar` (или, если на винде, то `C:\docstorage\foo\bar`). Если промежуточных каталогов не существует, то они рекурсивно создаются через `File.mkdirs()`. Права на запись в docstorage есть, всё нормально сохраняется, проблем никаких. Проблемы начинаются, если на вход приходит кривой путь (типа `docstorage/foo/bar`) - такого каталога нет, но Java воспринимает эту строку как путь относительно Class Path, превращая в абсолютный путь вида `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\config\docstorage\foo\bar` (на винде).

Это не соответствует моим ожиданиям. Надо либо сохранять файл ровно туда, куда сказано, либо кидать ошибку, что путь кривой. Вопрос: как это проконтролировать в коде? Paths.get() никаких проблем в такой ссылке не видит и спокойно её пропускает.

Понятно, что можно просто в лоб проверять, начинается ли путь со слэша или с буква-двоеточие-слэш (в зависимости от текущей операционки), но, может, есть менее кустарные способы валидации?

Comment: То что вы хотите называется абсолютным путем. На сколько я помню у Path есть метод проверки, что он абсолютный.

Comment: Точно, path.isAbsolute() работает! То, что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: на всякий случай: 
если строка приходит не из доверенного источника (например с клиента на сервер), то ее лучше вообще не использовать для пути к файлу. 
А взять, например, хэш.

Comment: Строка приходит из БД, но базист позарез хочет, чтобы я его контролировал, "потому что мало ли что я там у себя в таблице случайно не так поправлю". Тащемта, он прав в том, что кривой путь не должен приводить к сохранению файла в кишках джавы, а должен выбрасывать ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(path);
if (file.isDirectory()) {
  // сохраняем файл
} else {
  // бросаем ошибку
}
```

Comment: Если бы вопрос был "как проверить, что директория существует", то ваш ответ бы на него отвечал. Но вопрос совершенно другой.

Comment: @AarneAvialaynen, *Проблемы начинаются, если на вход приходит кривая ссылка (типа docstorage/foo/bar) - такого каталога нет, но Java считает себя самой умной и воспринимает эту строку как путь относительно своих кишков, превращая в абсолютный путь. Такого быть не должно. Надо либо сохранять файл ровно туда, куда сказано, либо кидать ошибку, что путь кривой.*. Вы называете ссылкой путь к директории, поэтому я так и ответил про "кривой путь каталога"

Comment: Окей, поправил пост.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать пакет nio:

```
String directory = "C:\Temp\somedir";
Path file = Paths.get(directory);
boolean isExist = Files.exists(file);
```

Comment: Вот из-за таких ответов в интернете мне и пришлось создавать отдельный вопрос. File.exists не является универсальным решением для любых проблем, связанных с java.io.File. Проверка на существование файла или папки никак не поможет в методе, задача которого - создавать этот файл и весь путь до него.

Comment: Files.exists никак не связан с java.io.File